# Analysing CRT Dependencies in a DLL manifest

Tags: c++, dll, side-by-side

I am using Visual Studio 2005 to build a DLL. By opening the DLL in a text editor I can see that it refers to multiple MS CRTs as follows. How can I find the name of DLL which the dependency elements refer to? I am trying to specifically find the source of the dependency which links to the 8.0.50727.5592 version of the CTR, it is the last one.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you use a binary or text editor you see always only the immediate references. What others DLLs do you mean? Or are you looking for msvcr80.dll? Look in C:\Windows\WinSxS.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you're getting the dependency injected automatically because you're linking against a 3rd party library that uses a different version of the runtime that you're using. Check the libraries against which your dll links and most likely one of them will have the exact extra dependency that you have there. By the way, you can use VS2005 to open a dll and look at its embedded manifest.

Comment: I believe this is the problem. However although I have double checked the dependencies, I wasn't able to figure out which 3rd party is referring to the latest CRT.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but I had the same issue and found a great tool to list all dependencies for any included libs.  I use VS 2010:
In command prompt, go to Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin and run command:
link /dump /directives libpathandname.lib
This will list out all linker dependencies including exact CRT versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it will tell you exactly what you need in this instance, but [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) may shed some light on it.  It'll show which of the dependent dlls depend on the CRT and it may show the versions from the manifests, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. But depends.exe didn't help about this issue.